# Javascript hover close not working on the right area

Tags: javascript, hover

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my dropdown menu? It needs to close when I move the mouse away from 'WEDDINGS', but it will only close when I move the mouse away from the top menu.

http://www.wedevents.com.au/weddings.asp

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/index.asp"> 
        <img src="/images/menu_home.gif" name="home" onMouseOver="over(0)" onMouseOut="out(0)" alt="Home" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/about.asp"> 
        <img src="/images/menu_about.gif" name="about" onMouseOver="over(1)" onMouseOut="out(1)" alt="About" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="ddmhover">
        <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/weddings.asp"> 
        <img src="/images/menu_weddings.gif" name="weddings" onMouseOver="over(2)" onMouseOut="out(2)" alt="Weddings" /></a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/grand.asp">Grand Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/premium.asp">Premium Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/platinum_beach.asp">Platinum Beach Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/prestige.asp">Prestige Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/beach.asp">Beach Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/garden.asp">Garden Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/intimate.asp">Intimate Package</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/reception.asp">Reception Packages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/planning.asp">
        <img src="/images/menu_planning.gif" name="planning" onMouseOver="over(3)" onMouseOut="out(3)" alt="Planning" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/gallery.asp">
        <img src="/images/menu_gallery.gif" name="gallery" onMouseOver="over(4)" onMouseOut="out(4)" alt="Gallery" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="ddmhover2">
        <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment.asp">
        <img src="/images/menu_equipment.gif" name="equipment" onMouseOver="over(5)" onMouseOut="out(5)" alt="Equipment" /></a>
        <ul class="subnav2">
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment01.asp">Portable Gazebo</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment02.asp">Welcome Easel</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment03.asp">Wishing Well</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment04.asp">Chairs, Covers &amp; Sash</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment05.asp">Americana Chairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment06.asp">Church Pews</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment07.asp">Wedding Umbrellas</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment08.asp">Handcrafted Pedestals</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment09.asp">Bollards &amp; Handrail</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment10.asp">Silk Flower Arrangements</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment11.asp">Red Carpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment14.asp">White Carpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment12.asp">Ceremonial Arch</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/equipment13.asp">Instant Marquee</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.wedevents.com.au/contact.asp">
        <img src="/images/menu_contact.gif" name="contact" onMouseOver="over(6)" onMouseOut="out(6)" alt="Contact Us" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:** (I copied and modified this...excuse the mess!)

```
ul.topnav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 85px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 630px;
    height: 36px;
    background: #b09a27;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: left;
}
ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base for sub navigation--*/
}
ul.topnav li  img{
    border: 0;
}
ul.topnav li a{
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}
/*--ul.topnav li a:hover{
    background: url(/images/ddm_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;
}--*/
ul.topnav li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
    width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    background: url(/images/subnav_btn.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
ul.topnav li span.subhover { /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/
    background-position: center bottom;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.topnav li ul.subnav, ul.subnav2 {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
    left: 0;
    top: 35px;
    /*--background: #333;--*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    /*--border: 1px solid #111;--*/
}
ul.topnav li ul.subnav li, ul.subnav2 li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    /*--border-top: 1px solid #252525;--*/ /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    /*--border-bottom: 1px solid #444;--*/ /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    clear: both;
    width: 170px;
}
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a, ul.subnav2 li a {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background: #B09A27 url(/images/ddm_right_arrow.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a:hover, ul.subnav2 li a:hover { /*--Hover effect for subnav links--*/
    background: #B09A27 url(/images/ddm_right_arrow.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
    color: #d0bd73;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:** (top half is for WEDDINGS and bottom half is for EQUIPMENT)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.topnav li.ddmhover").hover(function() { //When trigger is hovered...

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on hover

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow').stop(true,true); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });
    $("ul.topnav li.ddmhover2").hover(function() { //When trigger is hovered...

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav2").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on hover

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav2").slideUp('slow').stop(true,true); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... There is a lot of redundant code an unnecessary DOM traversal in there.  It would be better to write a generalized function that creates both menus.  I think I spotted the problem, it will take a few minutes to write it up properly.

Comment: Unless there is a situation where you could have two '.topnav' blocks on the same page you should consider turning 'topnav' into an id instead of a class.  Because of the way selector engines work jQuery will find "#topnav > ul.ddmhover" a lot faster than it will find "li.topnav ul.ddmhover"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.topnav li.ddmhover").hover(function() { //When trigger is hovered...

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on hover

        // Right here you are attaching to .ddmhover's parent ".topnav",
        // not .ddmhover, so it is sliding up when you mouseOut of ".topnav"
        // This should be in a function that is a second parameter to your first
        // .hover() call instead of this...
        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow').stop(true,true); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
});
```

**Updated**

I rewrote it to be more generalized.  This way you don't need to have a separate classname for each drop-down and subnav you create. Instead you just use ".ddmhover" and ".subnav" for them all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.ddmhover").mouseover(function() {
        var that = this,
        subnav = $(this).find("ul.subnav"),
        img = $(this).find('img'),
        subnavTimeout;

        $(this).addClass("subhover");
        subnav.slideDown('fast');

        var hideSubnav = function (evt) {
            // Wait half a second before trying to hide subnav
            subnavTimeout = setTimeout( function () {
                $(subnav).unbind('mouseleave');
                $(subnav).slideUp('slow');
                $(that).removeClass("subhover");
            }, 500);
        };

        $(subnav).mouseleave(hideSubnav)
        // since the title image fills the whole .ddmhover li we must attach to the image itself
        $(img).mouseleave(hideSubnav);

        // If the mouse entered the subnav don't close the subnav
        $(subnav).mouseenter(function () {
            clearTimeout(subnavTimeout);
        });
    });
});
```

We all do it from time to time, but Whenever you find yourself copy/pasting a chunk of code and then changing one or two strings it would be best to instead create a generalized method of dealing with it.

Comment: Actually, the sub-menu now disappears when the mouse tries to move onto the sub-menu. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, since you were using hover I assumed the HTML structure was a little different, easy to fix... While I'm at it I'll mention that each of the menu title images should have a title or alt attribute so blind users and search engines know what each menu item is named.

Comment: Nice...slick! Thanks again. So, I can remove the "2" after subvav in the css and html? I assume that's why the Equipment menu isn't working now.

Comment: Yeah, just give a ".ddmhover" and ".subnav" class to any item you want to have a drop down menu.  This is they way a class should be used, it is used to define a _type_ of thing.  Before you were using different classes to identify _specific_ things, that is what an id if for. If you need to refer to a specific element give it an id, it is much faster for jQuery (or any selector engine) to find something by id than it is finding it by class or tagname, that's why I suggested turning `.topnav` into `#topnav`.

Comment: Great! This time it's perfect. Thanks for all the additional mods. I really appreciate your help, especially for grouping it all back into a single set, rather than my split fail.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you're trying to do and I'm here to tell you that the way you're doing it is **completely** wrong. I tried to work with your code but it was not a viable option; instead what I Did was take the time to do a `jsfiddle` example with a "bare" working example of how you should implement a dropdown navigation with jQuery.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/mkDKz/

Look into it.

Comment: I will definitely bare this in mind when I need to make another one from scratch. Thank you very much for your response!